# Ying and Yang P5.js

Tags: p5.js

I'm currently trying to make a Ying and Yang symbol spin using a circular path. SO far I have made the medium and smaller ones rotate just fine. However, the stationary arc's are wrecking the illusion. Here is an open link to see my current code.

https://editor.p5js.org/Nathan65bmx/sketches/PAu3xx6Bd

Just looking for someone to help me make it look like it is rotating properly.

Comment: Stick the half circles to the circles and also rotate them, with the circles

Comment: There is a rotate() function you could use.

Answer (score 1):

Draw all shapes from a common central point, then use the rotate() function. https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/rotate Here's the link.
Do ask if you need help modifying the code.

[EDIT]
Here's the working version

```
function setup() {
  createCanvas(600, 600);
  angleMode(DEGREES);
  a = 0;
  x = 180;
}

let ANGLE = 0
let a;
let x;

  function draw() {
  background(180, 13, 123);
  //Big Circle
  noStroke();
  
  //Change starts from here
  push();
  translate(300, 300);
  rotate(a);
  fill("black");
  arc(0, 0, 300, 300, 0, x);
  fill("white")
  arc(0, 0, 300, 300, x,0);
  pop();
  a+=2;
  //Till here
  
  
  // Medium Circles
  fill("black");
  let CENTRE_X4 = width / 2;
  let CENTRE_Y4 = height / 2;
  let RADIUS4 = 75;
  let X4 = RADIUS4 * cos(ANGLE);
  let Y4 = RADIUS4 * sin(ANGLE);
  ellipse(CENTRE_X4 + X4, CENTRE_Y4 + Y4, 150);
  fill("white");
  let CENTRE_X3 = width / 2;
  let CENTRE_Y3 = height / 2;
  let RADIUS3 = 75;
  let X3 = RADIUS3 * cos(ANGLE);
  let Y3 = RADIUS3 * sin(ANGLE);
  ellipse(CENTRE_X3 - X3, CENTRE_Y3 - Y3, 150);

  // Small Circles
  fill("white");
  let CENTRE_X = width / 2;
  let CENTRE_Y = height / 2;
  let RADIUS = 75;
  let X = RADIUS * cos(ANGLE);
  let Y = RADIUS * sin(ANGLE);
  ellipse(CENTRE_X + X, CENTRE_Y + Y, 50);
  fill("black");
  let CENTRE_X2 = width / 2;
  let CENTRE_Y2 = height / 2;
  let RADIUS2 = 75;
  let X2 = RADIUS2 * cos(ANGLE);
  let Y2 = RADIUS2 * sin(ANGLE);
  ellipse(CENTRE_X2 - X2, CENTRE_Y2 - Y2, 50);
  ANGLE = ANGLE + 2;
  }
```

All the edits have been done using the push() & pop() and rotate() functions.
Hope this has helped!

Answer (score 1):

My answer is not adding anything new to Ruskin's great answer suggesting [`rotate()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/rotate) as well as [`push()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/push)/[`pop()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/pop), but wanted to mention that you could isolate the drawing instructions into a re-usable function and additionally simply reduce some of complexity and repetition (see [D.R.Y](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)):

```js
function setup() {
  createCanvas(600, 600);
  angleMode(DEGREES);
}

function draw() {
  background (200, 13, 123);
  // isolate coordinate system
  push();
    // move everything to the center
    translate(width / 2, height / 2);
    // rotate everything from the center
    rotate(frameCount % 360);
    // draw ying Yang
    drawYingYang(300);
  // return to the original coordinate system (0,0 = top left)
  pop();
}

function drawYingYang(outerDiameter){
  let innerYOffset  = outerDiameter / 4;
  let outerRadius   = outerDiameter / 2;
  let innerDiameter = innerYOffset / 1.5;
  // Big Circle
  noStroke();
  fill("black");
  arc(0, 0, outerDiameter, outerDiameter, -90, -270);
  fill("white")
  arc(0, 0, outerDiameter, outerDiameter, 90, 270);
  // Medium Circles
  fill("black");
  ellipse(0, innerYOffset, outerRadius);
  fill("white");
  ellipse(0, - innerYOffset, outerRadius);
  // Small Circles
  fill("white");
  ellipse(0, innerYOffset, innerDiameter);
  fill("black");
  ellipse(0, - innerYOffset, innerDiameter);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.1.9/p5.min.js"></script>
```

If that's the only thing you want to draw, removing `push()`/`pop()` won't make a difference visually, however, if you want to draw other shapes it will much easier to have independent control over where each shape is drawn